# substr within a while loop PHP SQL

Tags: php, substr

I have had to resort to posting on here, totally lost on this one!

I have an array which i can successfully print as it should, but i need to limit how may characters are printed. I know this can be done with substr however i am cannot seem to place substr onto the value i need to limit.

I understand using $variable = substr in a single line, but i am unable to implement with the array i am using, and i have searched high and low for any documentation that might clarify my issue but sadly to no avail.

Heres the code, in this case its the array $info and the value .info['post_content'].

```
 mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("xxxxxxxxx") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE hushfeed_showon = 1") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 
    } 

 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 


echo "<div>
<ul class='blocks-thumbs thumbs-rollover'>
    <li>
        <a href='single.html' class='thumb' title='An image'><img src='img/dummies/282x150.gif' alt='Post' /></a>
        <div class='excerpt'>
            <a href='dnb/a_Post.php?postid=".$info['postid']."' class='header'>".$info['post_title'] ."</a>
            <p class='para1'>" .$info['post_content']."</p>

        </div>
        <a href='single.html' class='link-button'><span>Read more &#8594;</span></a>
    </li>

</ul>
</div>";



}
```

Im struggling as i cannot find any info about using period during an echo ".$. "

If anyone could shed some light on where i should be focussing to handle this substr it would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Stu

Comment: `substr($info['post_content'], 0, number_of_chars_you_want_printed)`?

Comment: "Im struggling as i cannot find any info about using period during an echo `".$. "`" - that's [string concatenation](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: Have you tried looking at the PHP documentation?  There are plenty of examples of how to use `substr` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
echo "[...]<p class='para1'>" . 
      (strlen($info['post_content'])>200? 
          substr( $info['post_content'],0,200)."...": 
          $info['post_content']).
      "</p>[...]";
```

and the easy version:

```
 <?php
echo "[...]<p class='para1'>" . substr( $info['post_content'],0,200) . "</p>[...]";
```

Comment: Cheers John! Works awesome, i see exactly where i was going wrong now, many thanks!!